# Semantic UI menu Stick erro: "Sticky: Element is hidden, you must call refresh after element becomes visible "

Tags: semantic-ui

Estou usando `Semantic UI`, e na utilização de Menu `Sticky`, quando ele é "escondido" para resoluções inferiores a 630px, com o código abaixo:

```
    @media all and (max-width: 630px){
    #top_menu {
        display: none;
    }
    #m_btn{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0px auto;
    }
}
```

é apresentado um botão, até ai tudo funciona normal, mas quando acesso o home do site apresenta o erro :

> "Sticky: Element is hidden, you must call refresh after element 
>   becomes visible "

Alguém saberia me dizer como corrigir o erro relatado?

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html#/usage), por questões de performance, o comportamento padrão exige que você manualmente chame o método `$('.ui.sticky').sticky('refresh');` sempre que o elemento é modificado:

> Sticky uses mutation observers to adjust its position when content is added to the context, and also will automatically recalculate on browser resize, but any other changes to your page that adjust the elements context require you to refresh the sticky's position

No entanto, há uma ["solução definitiva"](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sticky.html#/settings) que permite a atualização automática:

```
$('.ui.sticky').sticky({
  context: '#exemplo',
  observeChanges: true
});
```